# KDE desktop strange appearance

Tags: arch-linux, kde, desktop-environment

I installed Arch Linux with XFCE 4.10 on my old PC with Intel 3.0 GHz processor, 4 GB RAM and Nvidia GeForce 7300 LE with nouveau driver and everything is running fine. I recently installed KDE (kdebase), modified `.xinitrc` file and start it using `startx` and I get this screen:

[image]

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem on an old Mac Pro. I asked for help on a KDE forum:

http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=118331

In summary, this answer worked for me:

*Try disabling compositing by pressing Alt + Shift + F12. If this causes the graphical corruption glitches to go away, then you might want to install the appropriate drivers for your system if it uses a Nvidia / ATI card/chip as they will likely work much better - and shouldn't experience this graphical distortion you are reporting.*

Once you can read the screen, you can to into System Settings > Desktop Effects and make this change "permanent".